# Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext and EJB @RolesAllowed in JBoss

Tags: java, security, servlets, asynchronous, jboss

reading new Servlet 3.0 specifications, I found startAsynch method for HttpServletRequest, which claims to make things in asynchronous way propagating the right contextual information to the passed runnable.

I wrote this code inside doGet method of my servlet:

```
@EJB  
private EJBManagerLocal manager;  

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {  
     if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null && request.isUserInRole("admin"))  
          //Method protected by @RolesAllowes("admin") annotation EJB-side  
          manager.verify();  

     final AsyncContext ctx = request.startAsync(request,response);  
     ctx.start(new Runnable(){  
          HttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)ctx.getRequest();  
          if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null && request.isUserInRole("admin"))  
               //Method protected by @RolesAllowes("admin") annotation EJB-side  
               manager.verify();  
     });  
}
```

When calling manager.verify() the first time, outside AsyncContext everything works fine, but when entering inside the Runnable in debug, i can see that, even the 'if' is succesfully passed (so the principal has been correctly propagated to the Runnable in AsyncContext), when calling the EJB method protected by the @RolesAllowed annotation, JBoss throws an exception saying that "The invocation of method verify" is not allowed.

Can anyone help me?

Platform: JBoss EAP 6.2.0

EDIT: Same behavior in JBoss EAP 6.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which claims to make things in asynchronous way propagating the right
>   contextual information to the passed runnable.

The propagation to runnable is met, you are able to access the principal and their roles.

```
if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null && request.isUserInRole("admin"))
```

I think the best approach for ejb asynchronous invocations is use [@Asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation.

See also: [Asynchronous Method Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

EDIT:

According [Java™ Servlet Specification Version 3.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/):

> Java Enterprise Edition features such as Section 15.2.2, “Web
>   Application Environment” on page 15-174 and Section 15.3.1,
>   “Propagation of Security Identity in EJB™ Calls” on page 15-176 are
>   available only to threads executing the initial request or when the
>   request is dispatched to the container via the `AsyncContext.dispatch`
>   method.  Java Enterprise Edition features **may** be available to other
>   threads operating directly on the response object via the
>   `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)` method.

See this thread in jboss forum, is a similar problem: [Anonymous principal when invoking EJB from a thread inside a servlet](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243368).

Comment: Hi Federico, thanks for your answer, yes it's true that the context is correctly propagated to the runnable...but I'm asking why servlet context got from the Async one has the principal and the EJB context doesn't... I was expecting also principal propagation between contexts with this approach. Unfortunately I can't use Asynchronous EJB, because I'm using threads for improving UI performances, not data loading

Comment: @Antlia I've updated the answer with more info. I think jboss not implement the propagation in a runnable when this execute from AsyncContext.start(Runnable).

Comment: Many thanks for the docs you've posted, I've searched all over the web and found anything.
For the link you've posted on JBoss forum, it have been posted from my account :D